# PlyQL queries usage

Tags: druid

I am new to Druid and PlyQL and i could not find any guides on how to use it. I have installed the package but where should i input the query from example (in documentation https://plywood.imply.io/plyql): 
`plyql -h 192.168.60.100:8082 -q 'SHOW TABLES'`

Answer (score 0):

The is a CLI command. You need to run this on terminal with appropriate parameters. Alternatively you can use any visualation tools for druid eg. [Grafana](https://grafana.com/), [Imply](http://imply.io) or [Turnilo](https://github.com/allegro/turnilo).